# Module.new with class_eval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

This is a large commit. But I want you to concentrate on this change block. http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d916c62cfc7c59ab6411407a05b946d3dd7535e9#L2L1304

Even without understanding the full context of the code I am not able to think of a scenario where I would use

```
include Module.new {
  class_eval <<-RUBY
    def foo
       puts 'foo'
    end
  RUBY
}
```

Then end result is that in the root context (self just before `include Module.new`) a method called `foo` has been added.

If I take out the `Module.new` code and if I only leave `class_eval` in that case also I will have a method called `foo` in `self`.

What am I missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [dig in the documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/append_features) you find that including a module will add the methods therein only if they are not already defined. So this approach will not overwrite the method in case it is already there.

Comment: look at this pastie http://pastie.org/956409 . Class will include the module only if that module is not already added. Since this is a brand new anonymous module it will always get added. another one http://pastie.org/956410

Comment: Well I haven't tried it - I just read the docs (and remembered that The Humble Ruby Book mentioned something like this). I guess there must be another reason there - or not, maybe it's just code chaos?

Answer (score 0):

This ActiveRecord code has been asked about in another question, where it received an excellent answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3473479/420947

However, the simplified eval string here removes the motivation to write this code, which is why it appears confusing.  In the unchanged code, the block binding captures a local variable used to reflect on the association: `#{reflection.name}.clear`.