# why use include module when class_eval by itself would suffice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the following code include module is used. The way I see it if include module is removed then also an instance method would be created. Then why user include module ?

http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1416

```
  include Module.new {
          class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
            def destroy                     # def destroy
              super                         #   super
              #{reflection.name}.clear      #   posts.clear
            end                             # end
          RUBY
        }
```

Comment: maybe ping the rails core guys?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all let's make one thing clear. When they call `super` inside the `class_eval` — it has absolutely nothing to do with why they used `include Module.new {}` thing. In fact the `super` which was called inside the `destroy` method is completely irrelevant to answering your question. There could be any arbitrary code inside that destroy method.

Now that we got it out of the way, here's what's going on.

In ruby, if you simply define a class method, and then define it again in the same class, you will not be able to call `super` to access the previous method.

For example:

```
class Foo
  def foo
    'foo'
  end

  def foo
    super + 'bar'
  end
end

Foo.new.foo # => NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `foo' for #<Foo:0x101358098>
```

This makes sense, because the first `foo` was not defined in some superclass, or anywhere up the lookup chain (which is where `super` points). However, you *can* define the first `foo` in such a way that when you later overwrite it — it will be available by calling `super`. This is exactly what they wanted to achieve with doing module include.

```
class Foo
  include Module.new { class_eval "def foo; 'foo' end" }

  def foo
    super + 'bar'
  end
end

Foo.new.foo # => "foobar"
```

This works, because when you include a module, ruby inserts it into the lookup chain. This way you can subsequently call `super` in the second method, and expect the included method to be called. Great.

However, you may wonder, why not simply include a module without all the tricks? Why are they using block syntax? We know that my above example is exactly equivalent to the following:

```
module A
  def foo
    'foo'
  end
end

class Foo
  include A

  def foo
    super + 'bar'
  end
end

Foo.new.foo # => "foobar"
```

So why didn't they do that? The answer is — the call to `reflection`. They needed to capture the variable (or method) which was available in the current context, which is `reflection`.

Since they are defining the new module using block syntax, all the variables outside of the block are available for usage inside the block. Convenient.

Just to illustrate.

```
class Foo
  def self.add_foo_to_lookup_chain_which_returns(something)
    # notice how I can use variable something in the class_eval string
    include Module.new { class_eval "def foo; '#{something}' end" }
  end
end

# so somewhere else I can do

class Foo
  add_foo_to_lookup_chain_which_returns("hello")

  def foo
    super + " world"
  end
end

Foo.new.foo # => "hello world"
```

Neat, huh?

Now let me stress it again. The call to `super` inside of the `destroy` method in your example has nothing to do with any of the above. They called it for their own reasons, because maybe the class where this is happening is subclassing another class which already defined `destroy`.

I hope this made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing but... they don't want to overwrite the "destroy" method, and want to leave it available to be overloaded by some end-user (you or me), without it removing this "reflection.clear" functionality.

So - by including it as a module, they can call "super" which will call the original destroy *or* the overloaded version (written by the end-user).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `include`, `destroy` method is not overwritten. It lands in ghost class that actual class derives from. That way, when one will call `destroy` on AR object, original one will be called, and `super` will call one from anonymous module (which will later call *original* `destroy` from class that it derived from).

A bit tricky, indeed.